# Necessity of braces when creating newcommand using csname

Tags: macros, expansion

Why does `\expandafter\newcommand\csname hello\endcsname{Hello world}` create a new macro while `\expandafter\newcommand{\csname hello\endcsname}{Hello world}` creates garbage?

Form what I understand, `\csname hello\endcsname` programatically creates a new string that can be used as a command name, in this case, something like `\hello`. You can write both `\newcommand\hello{Hello world}` and `\newcommand{\hello}{Hello world}` and they both work. So why is it that when csname is envolved, I have to use the form without curly braces surrounding the name?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The braces around the macro-to-be-defined name are optional; in your case, you either need an additional `\expandafter` or to remove the optional braces.

Comment: The \expandafter in the second case doesn't reach the \csname, it expands the brace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The “official” syntax for `\newcommand` is

```
\newcommand{<macro name>}[<args>]{<text>}
```

or

```
\newcommand{<macro name>}[<args>][<default>]{<text>}
```

but it turns out that the braces around the `<macro name>` are optional, so long as a single token appears. The braces are good for avoiding mistakes, but some self-control usually suffices.

With

```
\expandafter\newcommand\csname hello\endcsname{world}
```

the token `\hello` is built before `\newcommand` starts acting and absorbing its first argument (the story is much longer, actually, but this short explanation is precise enough).

On the other hand,

```
\expandafter\newcommand{\csname hello\endcsname}{world}
```

will try to expand the brace: `\expandafter` just acts on a single token, triggering its expansion, if the token is expandable, otherwise doing nothing. You *can* have the braces, if you prefer, but you need a further `\expandafter`:

```
\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname hello\endcsname}{world}
```

However this is too much for such a simple construction, isn't it?

If you find yourself in the position of having to do several of these definitions, it's “easy” to build a wrapper

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\newnamecommand{\@star@or@long\new@name@command}
\newcommand\new@name@command[1]{\expandafter\new@command\csname #1\endcsname}
\newcommand\renewnamecommand{\@star@or@long\renew@name@command}
\newcommand\renew@name@command[1]{\expandafter\renew@command\csname #1\endcsname}
\newcommand\providenamecommand{\@star@or@long\provide@name@command}
\newcommand\provide@name@command[1]{\expandafter\provide@command\csname #1\endcsname}
\makeatother

\newnamecommand{hello}{Hello World}
\newnamecommand*{helloarg}[1]{Hello #1}

\renewnamecommand{hello}{Whatever}

\providenamecommand{foo}{FOO}
```

Comment: It's also optional in the last argument, right? `\newcommand\foo\baz` works, if I remeber correctly.

Comment: @Manuel Yes, it turns out that such a simple form works, but I wouldn't advertise it.

Comment: You say: "The braces are good for avoiding mistakes". No, in this case the braces only brings mistakes. Like `\newcommand{foo}` or something similar. So, the "official syntax" for `\newcommand` is one of many LaTeX bad ideas.

Comment: @wipet I don't understand; are you on a LaTeXit campaign? Lamport's manual is very consistent with the usage of braces. Instead of letting users ask themselves why braces here and not there, he used braces around every argument. Which is ***good*** for beginners, in my opinion; feel free to disagree, but, please, avoid being dogmatic.

Answer (score 4):

You need to supply an explicit control sequence for `\newcommand`, and `\csname <text>\endcsname` is not a control sequence until it is expanded.

Using

```
\expandafter\newcommand\csname hello\endcsname{<stuff>}
```

expands to

```
\newcommand\hello{<stuff>}
```

as a result of the `\expandafter` skipping over `\newcommand` and expanding `\csname hello\endcsname` to `\hello`. However,

```
\expandafter\newcommand{\csname hello\endcsname}{<stuff>}
```

expands to

```
\newcommand{\csname hello\endcsname}{<stuff>}
```

as `{` is not expandable, making `\expandafter` useless. If you want to use the "grouped interface for `\newcommand`", you would need an additional `\expandafter`:

```
\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname hello\endcsname}{<stuff>}
```

However, without it, `\newcommand` fails since there's no explicit control sequence.

[`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) provides a means around this via an interface to `\@namedef{<csname>}` (from the LaTeX kernel [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co)):

```
\csdef{<csname>}<args>{<stuff>}
```

That is, you can use

```
\csdef{hello}<args>{<stuff>}
```

`<args>` above are optional but take the `\def` form of argument specification (or pattern). That is, `#1` instead of `[1]`, say.

Comment: `\csdef` doesn't check whether the token is defined.

Comment: @egreg And doesn't work that way, it's the “`cs`” version of `\def`, not of `\newcommand`.

Comment: @Manuel Yes, it doesn't accept the number of arguments in brackets.

Comment: @Werner I would say more like `\csdef{<csname>}<args>{<stuff>}` :)

Comment: @Manuel: Sure thing. That's also how it's specified in the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf).