# How to implement \expandbefore, similarly to \expandafter?

Tags: macros, expansion, expl3, parameters

I am trying to define a new command, but specifying the new control string "on the fly" using `csname` and `endcsname`. *(This is for the purpose of implementing a dependency injection pattern.)*  **Alternatively, is there a way of doing this with `expl3`?

Normally, I have been using `\expandafter\newcommand` ... but in this use case, I would like to define the `csname` WITHIN `\newcommand`'s first parameter, like so:

```
\newcommand{\expandbefore\csname \GetCommandName \endcsname}[1]{\small I did it!!!}
\newcommand\expandbefore\csname \GetCommandName \endcsname{\small I did it again!!!}
```

I would like for everything within the braces to be expanded BEFORE `\newcommand` - ***but without relying on `\expandafter` before `\newcommand`***.

**Issues:**

- I am curious as to whether there is a normal way of doing this in LaTeX, without having to rely on another process input buffer hack, (with Lua).
- Adding `expandafter`, `nameuse`, `edef`, `let`, `csname`, etc, within the `\newcommand`'s parameter just results in an error to redefine those commands. (Even if in `{}` or `begingroup` closures.
- Trying to `\meaning` `\expandafter` to figure out how it works fails, (predictably, and funny too).

Comment: you would need to redefine `\newcommand` to do `\expandafter\oldnewcommand` where `\oldnewcommand` is the saved original version, but this would almost certainly break multiple packages, so I'd rather strongly advise that you don't do it.

Comment: Did you try `\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\GetCommandName}`?

Comment: `\csname` itself triggers expansion of expandable tokens while during its search for the matching `\endcsname` gathering the character-tokens that form the name of the control-sequence-token in question. Therefore `\csname\GetCommandName\endcsname` might work out as expansion of `\GetCommandName` will be triggered by `\csname`. All you might need to do is triggering `\csname`-expansion before `\newcommand` gets carried out: `\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname \GetCommandName \endcsname}[1]{\small I did it!!!}`

Comment: Perhaps you want to look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/317094/4427

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I (with slight modifications) quote my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338784/118714) to the question [Define a control sequence after that a space matters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/338450/118714) as it seems to apply to your question as well:

---

By applying the `#{`-notation, you can define macros whose last argument is delimited by an opening brace. Unlike with other argument delimiters that get removed when gathering arguments, TeX will leave a delimiting opening brace in place.
(Actually the mechanism isn't restricted to opening brace character tokens. You can use any token whose category code is 1 at definition time. Could as well be `#\WeIrd` after `\let\WeIrd={`  .)
Delimited arguments can be empty.

Therefore for obtaining a control sequence token from a set of tokens that expands to a set of character tokens which forms the name of the control sequence token in question both for defining and for calling that control sequence token, you can (by applying the `#{`-notation) invent a single control sequence `\name` which processes a brace delimited argument trailed by an undelimited argument (which is nested in braces). After having TeX fetch the arguments, you can have TeX whirl them around and apply `\csname..\endcsname` to the argument supplied inside braces. The name of the control sequence token in question can contain space tokens as well.

```
\makeatletter
%
\newcommand\name{}%
\long\def\name#1#{\UD@innername{#1}}%
%
\newcommand\UD@innername[2]{%
  \expandafter\UD@exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{#1}%
}%
%
\newcommand\UD@exchange[2]{#2#1}%
%
\makeatother
```

`\name foo{bar}` → expansion step 1:
`\UD@innername{foo}{bar}` → expansion step 2:
`\expandafter\UD@exchange\expandafter{\csname bar\endcsname}{foo}` → expansion step 3:
`\UD@exchange{\bar}{foo}` → expansion step 4:
`foo\bar`  .

In expansion contexts you would need four `\expandafter`-chains for obtaining the result.

As `\romannumeral` does not produce any token when encountering a non-positive number, you can add a bit of `\romannumeral`-expansion in order to reduce the amount of `\expandafter`-chains.

Either do `\romannumeral\name0 foo{bar}`. This way only one `\expandafter`-chain hitting the `\romannumeral`-token is needed.

Or have the `\romannumeral`-expansion "hardcoded" within the definition—this way two `\expandafter`-chains are needed. The first one for obtaining the topl-level-expansion of `\name`. The second one for inducing `\romannumeral`-expansion.

```
\makeatletter
%
\newcommand\name{}%
\long\def\name#1#{\romannumeral0\UD@innername{#1}}%
%
\newcommand\UD@innername[2]{%
  \expandafter\UD@exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}%
}%
%
\newcommand\UD@exchange[2]{#2#1}%
%
\makeatother
```

**With such a macro you are not bound to specific definition commands:**

`\name{foo}` → `\foo`  .    *(←This is the way in which you do not define but just call/use control-sequences by means of `\name`.)*

`\name\newcommand{foo}` → `\newcommand\foo`  .

`\name\DeclareRobustCommand{foo}` → `\DeclareRobustCommand\foo`  .

`\name\global\long\outer\def{foo}` → `\global\long\outer\def\foo`  .

`\name\expandafter{foo}\bar` → `\expandafter\foo\bar`  .

`\name\let{foo}=\bar` → `\let\foo=\bar`  .

`\name\string{foo}` → `\string\foo`  .

`\name\meaning{foo}` → `\meaning\foo`  .

**You can as well use such a macro for defining/calling macros whose names
contain spaces:**

`\name{foo }` → `\foo␣`  .

`\name\newcommand{foo }` → `\newcommand\foo␣`  .

`\name\DeclareRobustCommand{foo }` → `\DeclareRobustCommand\foo␣`  .

`\name\global\long\outer\def{foo }` → `\global\long\outer\def\foo␣`  .

`\name\expandafter{foo }\bar` → `\expandafter\foo␣\bar`  .

`\name\let{foo }=\bar` → `\let\foo␣=\bar`  .

`\name\string{foo }` → `\string\foo␣`  .

`\name\meaning{foo }` → `\meaning\foo␣`  .

**While gathering the name of the control sequence token in question, `\name` will trigger expansion of expandable tokens :**

```
\def\GetCommandName{FooBar}
\name\newcommand{\GetCommandName}[1]{\small I did it!!!}
```

→ `\newcommand\FooBar[1]{\small I did it!!!}`

```
\def\GetCommandName{\CommandNamePartA\CommandNamePartB}
\def\CommandNamePartA{Ba}
\def\CommandNamePartB{r\InnerCommandNamePart o}
\def\InnerCommandNamePart{Fo}
\name\newcommand{\GetCommandName}{\small I did it again!!!}
```

→ `\newcommand\BarFoo{\small I did it again!!!}`

**You can also nest the calls to `\name`:**

**Example 1:**

`\name\name\expandafter{f o o }{b a r }`

Processing the first `\name` yields:
   `\name\expandafter\f␣o␣o␣{b a r }`  .

Processing the second `\name` yields:
   `\expandafter\f␣o␣o␣\b␣a␣r␣`  .

(Analogously: `\name\name\let{f o o }={b a r }` → `\let\f␣o␣o␣=\b␣a␣r␣`.)

**Example 2:**

`\name\name\name\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{f o o }\expandafter{b a r }{c r a z y }`

Processing the first `\name` yields:
   `\name\name\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\f␣o␣o␣\expandafter{b a r }{c r a z y }`  .

Processing the second `\name` yields:
   `\name\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\f␣o␣o␣\expandafter\b␣a␣r␣{c r a z y }`  .

Processing the third `\name` yields:
   `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\f␣o␣o␣\expandafter\b␣a␣r␣\c␣r␣a␣z␣y␣`  .

**Example 3:**

In expansion contexts you can use `\romannumeral`-expansion in order to keep things going.

`\romannumeral\name\name\name0 \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{f o o }\expandafter{b a r }{c r a z y }`

`\romannumeral` keeps expanding until it has found some number. In the end it will find the number`0` while with non-positive numbers `\romannumeral` will not deliver any token:
   `%\romannumneral-expansion in progress`
   `\name\name\name0 \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{f o o }\expandafter{b a r }{c r a z y }`

Processing the first `\name` yields:
   `%\romannumneral-expansion in progress`
   `\name\name0 \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\f␣o␣o␣\expandafter{b a r }{c r a z y }`  .

Processing the second `\name` yields:
   `%\romannumneral-expansion in progress`
   `\name0 \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\f␣o␣o␣\expandafter\b␣a␣r␣{c r a z y }`  .

Processing the third `\name` yields:
   `%\romannumneral-expansion in progress`
   `0 \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\f␣o␣o␣\expandafter\b␣a␣r␣\c␣r␣a␣z␣y␣`  .

Now `\romannumeral` finds the number `0`. Therefore `\romannumeral`-expansion gets aborted and `\romannumeral` won't deliver any token:
   `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\f␣o␣o␣\expandafter\b␣a␣r␣\c␣r␣a␣z␣y␣`  .

Be aware that `\name` internally applies `\csname` while

- expansion of expandable tokens takes place while `\csname` during its search for the matching `\endcsname` gathers the character tokens that form the name of the control sequence token in question.
- applying `\csname` as a side effect yields assigning the control sequence in question the meaning of the `\relax`-primitive in case the control sequence in question was undefined before applying `\csname`. That assignment will be restricted to the current scope even if the `\globaldefs`-parameter had a positive value at the time of applying `\csname`.

```
%%\errorcontextlines=1000
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}%

\parindent=0cm
\parskip=\medskipamount

\makeatletter
\newcommand\name{}%
\long\def\name#1#{\romannumeral0\UD@innername{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@innername[2]{%
  \expandafter\UD@exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\makeatother


\name\newcommand{foo}[2]{%
  Control sequence whose name does not contain any space.\\
  Argument 1: \textit{\textlangle#1\textrangle}\\
  Argument 2: \textit{\textlangle#2\textrangle}
}%

\name\newcommand{foo }[2]{%
  Control sequence whose name has a trailing space.\\
  Argument 1: \textit{\textlangle#1\textrangle}\\
  Argument 2: \textit{\textlangle#2\textrangle}
}%

\name\newcommand{ f o o }[2]{%
  Control sequence whose name is interspersed with spaces.\\
  Argument 1: \textit{\textlangle#1\textrangle}\\
  Argument 2: \textit{\textlangle#2\textrangle}
}%

\newcommand*\GetCommandName{\CommandNamePartA\CommandNamePartB}
\newcommand*\CommandNamePartA{Ba}
\newcommand*\CommandNamePartB{r\InnerCommandNamePart o}
\newcommand*\InnerCommandNamePart{Fo}
\name\newcommand{\GetCommandName}{\small I did it again!!!}

\begin{document}

\name{foo}{Arg 1}{Arg 2}

\name{foo }{Arg 1}{Arg 2}

\name{ f o o }{Arg 1}{Arg 2}

Nesting \texttt{\string\name}:

\name\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\expandafter{C o N f u SiO n}\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral\name\name\name0 %
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{F O O}\expandafter{B A R}{C R A Z Y}%
}%
\texttt{\name\string{C o N f u SiO n} is \name\meaning{C o N f u SiO n}}%
\\

Playing around with expandable tokens:  

\texttt{\name\string{\GetCommandName}:}
\texttt{\name\meaning{\GetCommandName}}

\name{\GetCommandName}%

Playing around with grouping:

%Be aware that \texttt itself opens up a new scope for typesetting its argument.

%\globaldefs=1\relax

\texttt{%
  \begingroup\name\string{w e i r d } is  \name\endgroup\meaning{w e i r d }%
}%

\texttt{%
  \name\string{w e i r d } is  \name\meaning{w e i r d }%
}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you have `\newcommand\name{}%` in front?  Just to test for duplicate commands?

Comment: Yes. To test for duplicate commands and to be informed about it via the " command-already-defined"-error-message that comes from `\newcommand` in case of the command in question already being defined.

Answer (score 9):

LaTeX already has a command form that takes the name of a command rather than the csname token:

```
\@namedef{\GetCommandName}{\small I did it!!!}
```

should do what you want this is simply `\expandafter\def\csname\GetCommandName\endcsname{..}`

Comment: Funny, I was trying to do it with @nameuse.  It would not be possible to go back and modify pre-existing `\newcommand`s with this, (let alone deal with the cat code nonsense).  But, I think your idea of overriding the pre-existing `\newcommand` would be ideal - if I could keep the code very similar to what it already is. The problem, of course, is I have no idea what `\@star@or@long \new@command` actually does, to incorporate what you are talking about.  Thank you very much, though.  It puts me on the right track.

Comment: @elikakohen If you like `\@nameuse`, you can do something like `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\newcommand\@nameuse{\GetCommandName}{\small I did it!!!}`.  The 1st `\expandafter` "hits" the 3rd `\expandafter` which "hits" `\@nameuse`. `\@nameuse` delivers `\csname\GetCommandName\endcsname` and vanishes. Then the 3rd `\expandafter`'s  work is done and it vanishes. Then the 1st `\expandafter`'s work is done and it vanishes. Now the 2nd `\expandafter` hits the `\csname` whose expansion in turn yields the control-sequence-token. When `\csname` is done, the 2nd `\expandafter` vanishes. :-) :-)

Comment: @UlrichDiez - Oh no, not at all.  I was just trying to figure out `@nameuse` and couldn't get it to work, (hence this question).  Based on your comment, though, I am certainly glad I didn't pursue that route!  Thanks!

Comment: @elikakohen You haven't said what your actual use case is but I can't think of any way that you could redefine `\newcommand` to do this that would not break any existing package that is using that command.